# How can I see which servers have mounted a shared NFS filesystem?

Tags: linux, nfs

I'm running Oracle Linux 6.2.  I have an NFS filesystem that is shared from one Linux server. Several other Linux servers mount this filesystem.  I need to find all the servers that have mounted the filesystem so I can properly unmount them for a migration to new storage.
I thought showmount was the command I needed, but it's not returning anything, and I know of at least 2 other servers that have mounted this filesystem.  Output of the showmount commands I've tried are below.

```
[root@prdjboss03 /]# showmount -e
Export list for prdjboss03:
/prdrepo 10.53.0.0/16

[root@prdjboss03 /]# showmount --all
All mount points on prdjboss03:
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Just so you know, this question is not really on topic here, we don't deal with professional systems. Next time, you might want to ask over on [unix.se] or [sf]. Are any of the remote systems using `autofs`? Are you _sure_ the remote systems currently have the drive mounted?

Comment: Are these NFSv4 exports we're talking about?

Comment: @SamiLaine, it appears I have both V3 and version 4 running when I run nfsstats.

Comment: @terdon.  Thanks for the info, I will keep that in mind for the next question. None of the 3 remote systems that have this drive mounted are using autofs, so I'm going to say autofs is not commonly used in this situation.

Comment: I went through the migration, but did not discover one of the servers that had mounted the old share.  I will attempt to build a test case in the lab that controls the variables discussed below to try and get a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

This command

```
  sudo ss -ntp | grep 2049
```

will show you the IP addresses of all the machines connected to your port 2049. Those are the clients of your network share.

Comment: Why port 445? IMHO that's CIFS; NFS should be port 2049.

Comment: @mpy thanks!! I answered for a samba share!! My bad. Edited as per your correction.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae.  Thanks.   The first time I ran that command on the server that is exporting the filesystem, I had no output.  After I cd'ed into the mounted directory on one of the servers that had the filesystem mounted, I got a partial list.

Comment: @user2299797 what you describe sounds like you _are_ using `autofs` and that shares are mounted only when you access them. Otherwise `cd`ing into the mount point should make no difference.